# How to prevent getting a Groovy Boolean in an Object array?

Tags: java, groovy, boolean

I am trying to create an Object array (Object[]) to be passed to a method ([IDescriptor](http://pele.farmbio.uu.se/nightly-1.3.1/cdk-javadoc-1.4.0/org/openscience/cdk/qsar/IDescriptor.html#setParameters%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)):

```
Object[] newValues = {
  Boolean.TRUE
}
descriptor.setParameters(newValues)
```

The particular descriptor expects the first value in the array to be a *java.lang.Boolean* object. However, it seems Groovy is converting to its own boolean class, and when I run the code (the above is not the full code), the descriptor reports that the first Object in the array is not a java.lang.Boolean object.

Not that it is very informative, this is the stacktrace:

```
org.openscience.cdk.exception.CDKException: The first parameter must be of type Boolean
        at org.openscience.cdk.qsar.descriptors.molecular.AromaticAtomsCountDescriptor.setParameters(AromaticAtomsCountDescriptor.java:118)
```

When I add an assert (repeated in the error), I get this error:

```
assert newValues[0] instanceof java.lang.Boolean
       |        |   |
       |        |   false
       |        AromaticAtomCountDescriptorParams$_run_closure3@1cc5069
       [AromaticAtomCountDescriptorParams$_run_closure3@1cc5069]
```

How can I make sure Groovy uses the Java Boolean class in the array, instead of its own richer class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the correct braces:

```
Object[] newValues = [ true ]
```

You used `{}` which creates a *closure*. That also works because closures have a lot of special abilities but they aren't lists are arrays. So Groovy wraps the single element on the right hand side in a list and then assigns the array `newValues`.

Comment: Cool, thanx! Yeah, the assert error message should have given me that hint!

Comment: I only knew because I once fell into the same trap. In my case, I was using `Map x = {...}` and closures work a lot like maps, so most code actually worked but in some odd case, it failed.